# Can't commit in Git. Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'

Tags: git, commit

I am really new to Git, and I faced this [image: problem]
So first i downloaded the zip from the Github, then i modified it, added my code etc. and tried to upload it(add,commit,push). I got the error like: No github repository detected. I did git init and upload it, but i could upload it to the fork that i forked from my team's repo. but i need to upload my files into the team's repo, not to the one that i forked

How could i fix this?

Comment: You haven't changed any file.

Comment: Please avoid taking screenshot for text messages. Rather copy paste all the messages as text. It helps readability and makes the question findable through google. That being said: what's printed when you run: `git status`?

Comment: How to fix what? You didn't show any problem in that screenshot. Btw, please do not post images of text or code. Copy the text using the Copy functionality of your OS (select the text using the mouse then right-click on it and select Copy) then paste it into the question editor and format it as code using the `{}` button from the editor's toolbar.

Comment: Use `git status` to find out what you have changed and what you have added to the index. The index is where the next commit is prepared.

Comment: $ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
@k0pernikus

Comment: my fault, i edited the question

Comment: Read the Git Book: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 It explains the principles of Git.

Comment: thnx i will, just the problem is i need to hand it right now. Its kinda urgent. School stuff u know

Answer (score 3):

```
git add .
```

command will track or stage all the modified files.

```
git commit -m "comment"
```

Will commit staged files to the repository.

Looks like it is really nothing to commit, because nothing was staged.
All the changes is really up to date.

You can use

```
git status
```

to check if there is something to commit

and also advice to not use

```
git add .
```

but specify file by file,

```
git add src/fileName.cs
```

because git doesn't work well with blobs. There is no well done history tracking for the blob (while logically it is correct). Once you added blob all the next modifications will be tracked as new file

Answer (score 1):

Just change something, for example add some comments or delete free space then try:

```
git add .
git commit -m "make it better"
```

git sees this as a new project